# Openerp 6.1:Display date range in sales order line

Tags: odoo

I am trying to show date range i.e, "date from" and "date to" in the search section of the sales.order.line but it doesn’t display it. I have attached my code below. What have I missed please:

class code:

```
from osv import fields, osv
class sales_invoice_date(osv.osv):
_name='sale.order.line'
_inherit='sale.order.line'
_columns={
    'ordered_date': fields.related('order_id', 'date_order', type='date',    relation='sale.order', select= 1, string='Date Ordered'),
    'due_date_from':fields.function(lambda *a,**k:{}, method=True, type='date',string="Due date from"),
    'due_date_to':fields.function(lambda *a,**k:{}, method=True, type='date',string="Due date to"),

}
sales_invoice_date()
```

View code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

    <record id="view_sale_orderlinedate" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.line.dateinherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_line_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="order_id" position="after">
                        <field name="ordered_date" />
                        </field>
            </field>

    </record>

    <record id="view_sale_orderlinedate2" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.line.dateinherit2</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
        <field name="type">search</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_uninvoiced_line_filter"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">


            <field name="product_id" position="after">
                        <field name="ordered_date" />
                        <field name="due_date_from" filter_domain="[('date_due','&gt;=',self)]"/>
                        <field name="due_date_to" filter_domain="[('date_due','&lt;=',self)]"/>
          </field>
          <field name="salesman_id" position="after">  
                        <field name="due_date_from" filter_domain="[('date_due','&gt;=',self)]"/>
                        <field name="due_date_to" filter_domain="[('date_due','&lt;=',self)]"/>
          </field>
        </field> 
    </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Thanks @Arya for the formatting.

Comment: I have been able to resolve it. I was actually linking to a wrong inherited reference: <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_uninvoiced_line_filter"/>

The right reference ID is: <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_line_filter"/>

Comment: The new error am having is this? What could be wrong? `ValueError: Invalid field 'date_due' in domain expression ['&', ('date_due', '>=', '2013-03-23'), ['date_due', '<=', '2013-03-23']]'

Comment: It seems `sale.order.line` does not have field name `date_due`.

Comment: thanks @Arya. That was the problem. I changed the date_due to the Ordered_date and it works.